# How to return dynamic field from restful json webservice

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, jackson

I have created restful   json webservice using Sprint MVC and jackson jars.
My controller looks like this :-

```
@Controller
public class AdminController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/fetchMyData", method = RequestMethod.POST)   
public @ResponseBody MyResponse getDynamicResponse(@RequestBody UserRequest userRequest) {                       

    MyResponse myResponse = someDAO.calldatabase("userRequest) ");
return myResponse; 
}
```

However, now my consumers don't want all the fields in response , as we have around 150 fields and they need 2 or 3 at a time. They will send the list of fields in request and I will need to same those fields only.

So now sometimes my output should be :-

```
{
"field1": "someValue",
"field2": "someOtherValue"
}
```

Other time it will be :-

```
{
"field1": "someValue",
"field2": "someOtherValue",
"field3": "someOtherValue"
}
```

Using some static annotation like *@JSONIgnore* or *@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true, value = {"field1"})* is not option as it will hardcode for everytime.

I can try overriding method of class *ObjectMapper* from Jackson by extending , but not sure how to tell my class to Spring MVC  during Serialization??

Easiest workaround is i can use annotation *@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)* but then I will not able to send null in response ?

Any thoughts or way to achieve return dynamic number of fields from my Spring MVC restful webservice on runtime ??

Comment: This should be useful: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureJsonFilter

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for pointer , with this also I am not sure how to point Sprint to use this filter at runtime :-( .

Comment: AFAIK, Spring doesn't have built-in support for filters. But you could write your own HttpMessageConverter implementation for a class containing an object to serialize and a FilterProvider, and return an instance of this class from your controller method. Maybe there's a better way, but that should be a working solution.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for quickly providing guidance

Comment: Similar question, hope this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20802032/limiting-fields-in-json-response-for-rest-api