# Programmatically ignore (omit) specific fields in JSON response of REST service WITHOUT altering the DTO object class

Tags: java, json, rest

I have a DTO class and some REST services that sometimes return (among other things) a List of those DTOs.

I cannot alter that DTO, as it's used in several places of the project.

However, **only for one specific REST service**, I need to exclude some of the fields of that DTO object.

Basically I need to be able to apply [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20806188/3069498) only at a certain point.

I tried applying `@JsonFilter("restrictionFilter")` to my DTO class, but then I get an error if I don't use that filter with a mapper every time I marshall the object into a JSON, like this:

```
final String writeValueAsString = mapper.writer(
  new SimpleFilterProvider()
    .addFilter("restrictionFilter", 
                SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept("name", "sizeInByte"))
  ).writeValueAsString(objectsList);
```

The error is *Cannot resolve PropertyFilter with id 'restrictionFilter'; no FilterProvider configured...*

Answer (score 0):

This issue sounds like a perfect Decorator design pattern use.
Create a new DTO with a constructor that gets the original DTO and create which get methods you want or ignore whatever get methods you like.
For example:

```
public class NewDto {

    OldDto oldDto;

    public NewDto(OldDto oldDto){
        this.oldDto = oldDto;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return oldDto.getName();
    }
}
```

Now you will only need to return the NewDto object, like so:

```
return new NewDto(oldDto)
```

Comment: This **is** my chosen solution as well :) , but  I was thinking there can be a less-verbose solution, using custom filters, like in the code sample that I gave.